# how can I capture web element and reuse it to for test in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I need help with followings. how do i search this object from page (Node_ID="3857511") and store value in variable and reuse it for test to search object by ID.

Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHlh3.png)

Comment: Which Selenium Client are you using? Your code trials please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `search` this object from page (Node_ID="3857511") and store value in variable you can use the following line of code :

- **`Java`**

  ```
  String my_id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='idea boundarynode nodeyellow textnode ui-droppable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle")).getAttribute("node_id");
  ```
- **`Python`**

  ```
  myID = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='idea boundarynode nodeyellow textnode ui-droppable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle").get_attribute("node_id")
  ```
- **`C#`**

  ```
  string myId = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='idea boundarynode nodeyellow textnode ui-droppable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle")).GetAttribute("node_id");
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer DebanjanB. I am very new to selenium and Java programming. What I want to do is, find unique object and capture NodeID attached to it. Use the NodeID to conduct rest of test.